# GCP Cloud Run: One off jobs and "Configuration <servicename> does not have any ready Revision

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have created a very simple image that performs an one-off job (prints some dummy logs) and exits as follows:

```
➣ $ cat Dockerfile
from alpine:latest

COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint

ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint"]

CMD ["100"]
```

...where

```
➣ $ cat entrypoint.sh
#!/bin/sh

ITERATIONS=${1:-1000}
counter=1

while [ "$counter" -le "$ITERATIONS" ]; do
    echo "Executing and logging iteration no $counter"
      counter=$(($counter + 1))
done
```

When trying to deploy to Cloud Run,

using the following command:

```
gcloud beta run deploy logger --image=pkaramol/logging --cluster=pkaramol-cloudrun
```

it fails with the following message that I cannot decode:

> Service name (logging):  logger Deploying container to Cloud Run on
>   GKE service [logger] in namespace [default] of cluster
>   [pkaramol-cloudrun] X Deploying new service... Configuration "logger"
>   does not have any ready Rev ision.
>     - Creating Revision...   X Routing traffic... Configuration "logger" does not have any ready Revisio   n. Deployment failed ERROR:
>   (gcloud.beta.run.deploy) Configuration "logger" does not have any
>   ready Revision.

... on some other occasions, it takes forever

```
Deploying container to Cloud Run on GKE service [mylogger] in namespace [default] of cluster [pkaramol-cloudrun]
⠶ Deploying new service... Configuration "mylogger" is waiting for a Revision
 to become ready.
  ⠶ Creating Revision...
  . Routing traffic...
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your container starts, it must launch a program that responds as an HTTP server on port $PORT (8080).

You can run just about any software in a container. The interface is HTTP Request/Response. The CPU is idled in between HTTP requests.

Your container does not follow the Cloud Run requirements and is terminated when Cloud Run detects no response / incorrect response on port $PORT.

Read this document to better understand the software requirements:

[Container runtime contract](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract)

Comment: Thanks for this elaborated answer. So it seems that Cloud Run is not an ideal solution for one off jobs (since I **have** to also serve sth on **PORT** and this is out of my scope), right?

Comment: @pkaramol - I don't know enough about your requirements. Create a new question with specifics.

Comment: As a side-effect of it's nature, Cloud Build can be used for one-off jobs.

Comment: @Grayside - Good point, I will remember that. Cloud Build has a narrow focus on what it can run but you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

GCP released [Cloud Run jobs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/create-jobs) back in 2022, this is probably what you need